# Compiler Switch in Android Studio

Tags: android

Is there a way to give the compiler a command that a piece of source code are not compile or compile ? Example :

```
        // To set the adView with some listener
    final AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            adView.clearFocus();
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    //request TEST ads to avoid being disabled for clicking your own ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)// This is for emulators
            //test mode on DEVICE (this example code must be replaced with your device uniquq ID)
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This piece of code I want for Version X and in Version Y this source code ignore if I build the APK. I would like to have two or more versions in one source code and I will control which source code is in the build APK.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure build variants DEBUG/RELEASE to execute code paths according to that. another option is to define multiple product flavors with product flavor variables that vary for each flavor.

Please check these links:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html
http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/

Comment: Thank you, the product flavors are the thing what I wanted.